# taking input from user to decide which object will be used in python class

Tags: python, class

i am new here and i am trying to learn python. i want to create a simple atm program but i also want to try something that i haven't seen yet. i want to take input from user and select one of objects of a class regard to this selection, here is the part of my code

```
class bankaccount():

    def __init__(self,name,money):

        self.name=name
        self.money=money

    def show(self):

        print(self.name,self.money)


johnaccount=bankaccount("john",500)
mikeaccount=bankaccount("mike",1000)
sarahaccount=bankaccount("sarah",1500)

selection= input("please write the name: ")
```

for example i will write john and program should run johnaccount.show is this possible? could you please help about this issue.

Comment: Put the objects into a `dict`, and then you can look it up directly.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Try `johnaccount.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "hacky" way to do that (see below). Usually you'd rather have a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) containing all of the accounts and then get the account from there.

For example:

```
accounts = {
  'john': bankaccount("john",500),
  'mike': bankaccount("mike",1000)
}

selection = input("please write the name: ")
if selection in accounts:
  print(f"Balance: {accounts[selection].show()}") 
else:
  print("Account not found")
```

The "hacky" way is to use Python's built-in [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function:

```
johnaccount=bankaccount("john",500)
mikeaccount=bankaccount("mike",1000)
sarahaccount=bankaccount("sarah",1500)

selection = input("please write the name: ")
account_name =  f"{selection}account"

if account_name in locals():
  print(f"Balance: {locals()[account_name].show()}") 
else:
  print("Account not found")
```

The `f"Balance: {accounts[selection].show()}"` syntax that I'm using is called [*f-strings*, or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals).

PS. it's [common practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) to use CamelCase for class names, e.g. `BankAccount`, and to use lowercase and underscores for [variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), e.g. `john_account`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, i will study these methods, and also i will pay attention my syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
class bankaccount():

    def __init__(self,name,money):
        self.name=name
        self.money=money

    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.money)

# build the accounts 'DB' (which is just a dict)
# read more here: https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/5-examples-using-dict-comprehension/
accounts = {name: bankaccount(name,balance) for name,balance in [("john",500),("mike",1000)]}

user = input("please write the name: ")

account = accounts.get(user)
if account:
  account.show()
else:
  print(f'no account for {user}')
```